Create a packed horizontal list with fixed rows in Flutter
How can I create a packed list of items with horizontal scrolling and fixed rows in Flutter? Wrap makes each item a fixed weight. I want to achieve the look of the attached image:


You can use the Column to create separated line of chips and fill it with calculated total chips / line count.
Workaround code below to demonstrate the result:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const line = 3;

  final chips = [
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Physics', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Meat', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Application', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Library', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Reception', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Wedding', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Food', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Emphasis', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Disease', count: 1950),
    ChipsWidget(label: 'Presence', count: 1950),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent.shade100,
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: List.generate(
              line,
              (id) => Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                height: 40,
                child: ListView.separated(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  separatorBuilder: (c, i) => SizedBox(width: 5),
                  itemCount: (chips.length / line).ceil(),
                  itemBuilder: (c, i) => chips.elementAtOrNull(
                    ((chips.length / line).ceil() * (id)) + i,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChipsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChipsWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    required this.count,
  });

  final String label;
  final int count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        shape: StadiumBorder(),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
        Text(label),
        SizedBox(width: 5),
        Text(count.toString()),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

And this is the result:

Hopefully it can solve your problem, Thanks 

If you only need the rows to scroll together (and manually decide which row each chip goes into), all you need is warp the rows in a column then put them in a horizontal scrollable.

class ChipGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChipGrid({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                  Chip(label: Text('Item Number $i')),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                for (var i = 10; i < 20; i++)
                  Chip(label: Text('Item Number $i')),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                for (var i = 20; i < 30; i++)
                  Chip(label: Text('Item Number(Row 3): $i')),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

